# How can i turn off change tracking when using EF and linq query?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm building my entity framework query like:

```
var users = from u in this.UserRepository.GetAll()
            join s in this.UserSales.GetAll()

            select new MyNewObject
            {
            ...
            }

return users.ToList();
```

How can I turn of change tracking for this call?

Comment: Only for that call or all calls?

Comment: Probably `AsNoTracking`, but it depends on what `GetAll()` returns and whether `this.UserRepository.GetAll()` and `this.UserSales` can be joined as one query at all. We need more details to answer this.

Comment: Just for a single call.

Answer (score 1):

If you are turning them off just for a specific call use [AsNoTracking()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

```
var myresult = query.Where(...).AsNoTracking().ToList()
```

Comment: AsNoTracking doesn't seem to be available for me, I'm using code first if that matters.

Comment: AsNoTracking was introduced in EF 5.  Are you using a version earlier then that?  Otherwise you might just be missing a reference (the reference would be listed in the link in my answer).

Comment: I have EF 6.01.  I am performing a projecting i.e. select MyNewObject {...} at the end, maybe that is why?  I updated my code above.

Comment: @user1361315 As I asked before, it all depends on what happens inside GetAll, what these methods return and whether both repositories share the same context instance. You can't expect an accurate answer without accurate details.

Comment: @GertArnold Sorry missed your comment.  Yes all the Repositories share the same Context.  GetAll is using a GenericRepository but I can't really paste it here. I look into that thanks as I think I'll have to add the NoTracking call there.